# How to search a sub string in string

Tags: java, string, search

I tried this code but this is not working for all strings.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Substring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str;
        String subStr;
        int count=0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String : ");
        str = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the Sub String : ");
        subStr = in.nextLine();

        for(int i =0 ; i <str.length(); i++)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i) == subStr.charAt(0))
            { 
                for(int j=0 ; j<subStr.length();j++)
                {
                    if( subStr.charAt(j) ==str.charAt(i+j))
                    count++;
                    else
                    {
                        count=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(count == subStr.length())
            System.out.println("Sub String Matched !!");
        else
            System.out.println("String does not match !!");

    }

}
```

What's wrong with this code ?

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what works and what doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

> How to search a sub string in string

You don't need to loop over whole `String`. You can use [`string.indexOf(subString)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to find the index of the substring in the string and it will return the index of the first occurrence of the substring. If you only want to ckeck whether String contains substring or not you can use [`string.contains(subString)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I don't want to use any inbuilt function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only work if the substring is the end of the original string. This is because your code does not check that the entire substring was matched until it exits the first `for` loop. I moved the `if (count == subStr.length() )` statement inside your first `for` loop and added a `break` if it finds the substring.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Substring {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str;
    String subStr;
    int count=0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the String : ");
    str = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the Sub String : ");
    subStr = in.nextLine();

    for(int i =0 ; i <str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) == subStr.charAt(0)) { 
            for(int j=0 ; j<subStr.length();j++) {
                if( subStr.charAt(j) ==str.charAt(i+j)) {
                    count++;
                } else {
                    count=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(count == subStr.length()) {
                System.out.println("Sub String Matched !!");
                //int index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
        if(count == 0){
            System.out.println("String does not match !!");
        }
}

}
```

Note: If you then want the index at which the substring (first) occurred, you can set `int index = i;` before breaking the loop as shown in the commented line above.

Another note: don't tend to omit the `{}`s in `if` and `else` statements. While, technically, you don't *need* them for single statements, it can cause bugs if you need to edit code later...

Answer (score 0):

Try to decipher to the logic behind the code, so in plain english your code does the following:

### LOGIC:

1)Enter a String via the Scanner and store it as str, do the same for the substring and store it as subStr.

2)Cycle through the each character of str via the for loop.

- If the **first character** of the subStr is equal to any character with in str, then cycle through the characters of subStr. If the characters beyond this index are equal then increment the count variable each time the letters in each String are equal at the following indexes.
- Else print String does not match.

3) If the number of similar characters in both Strings (denoted by the count variable) is equal to the length of the subString, then the subString is matched. Else no match.

---

### ANSWER

### So what went wrong?

I hope you notice on 2), The first bullet point you are only checking whether or not the first character of str is equal to the first character of subStr, if they are not equal you are then concluding that their is no match, which is false.

Consider the example:

str = "baloon"

subStr = "loon"

Your output would be: "String not matched"

This is because according to your code if 'b' != 'l' then theirs no match, which is false. That in essence is why your code does not work.

---

You could've just done the following:

```
    if(str.contains(subStr)){
                  System.out.println("Sub-string matched");
                  }
```